# Have intellij automatically format code and add types to variables/returns/parameters

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have code like this everywhere

```
val someName = 10
var someOtherName = "hello"
def add(a, b) = a + b
```

I prefer to have the types coded in (rather than the compiler figuring it out) in most of the code. It would be great if IntelliJ had some auto-format option to just add the types, so that the above becomes:

```
val someName: Int = 10
var someOtherName: String = "hello"
def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
```

Does a tool exist?

Comment: Do you want to add it in all the existing code ? If it is required only in some cases, you can manually do it by using the key combination "alt + enter" after the method/variable name. Then it will ask suggestion to add the method/variable type.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the comment from [Yadu Krishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925369/yadu-krishnan):

Do you want to add it in all the existing code ? If it is required only in some cases, you can manually do it by using the key combination "alt + enter" after the method/variable name. Then it will ask suggestion to add the method/variable type.

> It should be Yadu Krishnan to write this answer, if he does, please accept his response. I'm only making this one to become clearer that there is a solution, that worked in my case at least

Comment: This is a good tip to be aware of, but I want it for existing code, like in my example (where 3 lines exist with no types)